# Facebook graph API /User/Videos cannot read video with ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

the Facebook graph API docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos) say I should be able to read a video simply by using the video as the path, IE:

`https://graph.facebook.com/IDHERE?access_token=TOKENHERE`

However when I try that, even with user_videos permission, it says invalid request. And this is a video I uploaded with my software, so I should be able to view it without permissions (according to docs).

My error specifically is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "A8hsvflN57r"
    }
}
```

Also going to `/me/videos` shows a blank array called:

```
{
   "data": []
}
```

even though I have several uploaded videos.

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue. Does the access token you are using belong to user who own's the video? Does the access token you are using have the `user_videos` permission? Permissions needed are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Answer (score 1):

`/{user-id}/videos` end point will read only the videos in which you are tagged in.
pass `'uploaded'` as path parameter. 
Like this - `/{user-id}/videos/uploaded?access_token={access_token}`.
It will read all your uploaded videos.
Hope this will work.
Thanks